# How to match a value with my custom-object array

Tags: arrays, wpf, powershell

I'm having dificulties working with an array of custom objects and matching it with a variable.

I have a variable: `$CmbCust.SelectedItem` (currently selected item in a WPF form)

Custom-Object and the creation of my items in the combobox:

```
$CustomerFileArray = @()
    ForEach ($c in (Get-ChildItem $ProgramRoot\Customers -Filter Customer-*.xml | sort Name -descending)) {
        $XmlCustomer = [xml](Get-Content $ProgramRoot\Customers\$c)
        if ($XmlCustomer.Office365.Customer.Name -eq "") {
            $CustomerName = "- Geen naam"
        }
        Else {
            $CustomerName = $XmlCustomer.Office365.Customer.Name
        }
        $CustomerItem = New-Object PSObject
        $CustomerItem | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Name' -Value $CustomerName
        $CustomerItem | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'File' -Value $c
        $CustomerFileArray += $CustomerItem
        [void] $CmbCust.Items.Add($CustomerName)
    }

$CmbCust.SelectedItem = $XmlOffice365.Office365.Customer.Name
```

My question is, how can I match the value in $CmbCust.SelectedItem with my Array $CustomerFileArray's File property

The action I would like to do is to get a path of the selected item to remove it. I've Googled and came up with:

```
$RemoveFile = @()
$RemoveFile | where {$CustomerFileArray.ContainsKey($_.CmbCust.SelectedItem)}
Remove-Item $ProgramRoot\Customers\$RemoveFile -Force
```

But that doesn't seem to work...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `SelectedItem` property contains a string found in the `Name` property of one of the items in `$CustomerFileArray`, you should apply `Where-Object` to `$CustomerFileArray` like so:

```
$CustomerFileArray |Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $CmbCust.SelectedItem} |Select-Object -ExpandProperty File
```

This will return the `FileInfo` object you originally assigned to the `File` property of the corresponding object in the array